# ng-class with function and Expression

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I need to add two classes by using ng-class  ,one class I am getting by a function another I need to get by an expression -
Below is code which I am using but getting some syntax error -

```
 <div class="field-icon" ng-class="getFieldClass(entry.entry_type_id) , 'used':  entry_map[entry.guid] > 0" ></div>
```

What would be correct syntax if it is possible to use function and expression together.

Comment: you need to wrap it in curly braces ng-class="{getFieldClass(entry.entry_type_id) , 'used':  entry_map[entry.guid] > 0}"

Comment: @tpie, I very much doubt that it'll work. This is not a valid JS object definition

Comment: What's the return value of `getFieldClass`?

Comment: Is this a $scope function()???

Comment: @tpie Its not working ..

Comment: it wasn't an answer, it was a comment.  The syntax uses curly braces.

Comment: What's the return value of getFieldClass?  retrun some custom css class

Answer (score 15):

You had wrong `ng-class` syntax, it should be in JSON format like `ng-class="{'used':  expression2 }"`, expression will return `Boolean` on basis of that class will get added or removed from the class `attribute` value.

As your `getFieldClass` method is returning class name then you could shift your both class logic in `getFieldClass` method

**Markup**

```
<div class="field-icon" 
ng-class="getFieldClass(entry)" ></div>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.getFieldClass = function(entry){
   //use entry.entry_type_id here to decide class which is first
   //'text-box-icon' class has been selected on some condition based on entry.entry_type_id
   return {"text-box-icon": true, 'used': $scope.entry_map[entry.guid] > 0};
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can write both function and expression in array.

Example:

```
 <div class="field-icon" ng-class="[getFieldClass(entry.entry_type_id), {'used':entry_map[entry.guid] > 0}]"></div>
```

Live Example here: https://plnkr.co/edit/OWfkAwJiombrehiS7p9o?p=preview

Comment: I don't think your syntax is correct, need to wrap the expression in JSON, then put them in array. like: `[getFieldClass(entry.entry_type_id), {'used':entry_map[entry.guid] > 0}]`

Comment: Yes. I missed. Thanks for pointing out. I also updated live example

Comment: Thanks for your sample  with " [getFieldClass(entry.entry_type_id)]  "

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
<div class="field-icon" ng-class="getClasses(entry)"></div>
```

where your method looks like:

```
$scope.getClasses = function(entry) {
   var classes = {};
   if (entry_map[entry.guid] > 0)
      classes['used'] = true;

   if (various-logic)
     classes['custom-class-one'] = true;
   else if (various-logic)
     classes['custom-class-two'] = true;
   //etc

   return classes;
}
```